# Cannot find name eror while using namespace in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to understand the namespaces and modules in TypeScript.

Please see the sample code:

```
namespace ModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree{
       export class SomeClass{
           constructor(){};
            someVariableOne:any;
            someVariableTwo:any;
            someFunction= function(){someFunctionCode};
      };
}
```

But while using this SomeClass.

```
ModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree.SomeClass.someFunction();
```

I am getting this error as:

```
Cannot find name 'ModuleOne'
```

Please let me know If I'm doing something wrong or there is some other approach that I need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a different error:

> Property 'someFunction' does not exist on type 'typeof SomeClass'

([your code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20ModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20SomeClass%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20someVariableOne%3Aany%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20someVariableTwo%3Aany%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20someFunction%20%3D%20function()%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree.SomeClass.someFunction()%3B))

The reason is that `someFunction` is a property of the class instance, and not a static method.
It should be:

```
let instance = new ModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree.SomeClass();
instance.someFunction();
```

Or if you want a static method:

```
namespace ModuleOne.ModuleTwo.ModuleThree{
       export class SomeClass{
           static someFunction() { }

           constructor(){};
            someVariableOne:any;
            someVariableTwo:any;
      };
}
```

Comment: This is not the error that I'm getting, I even tried it in playground, did not give me any error. I'm using VS code. But having the error of cannot find name.

Comment: Well, the playground link in my answer does have a compilation error..  Unless of course the code in your question isn't the code you're trying to compile. Also, what version of typescript are you using?